# Can we add aws-managed grafana dashboard or charts with code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, charts, grafana, dashboard, embedding

I am reading docs https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/share-dashboards-panels/
there is a property which allows iframe but I am unsuccessful in embedding it into code.

Are you able to suggest some solution in which AWS-managed grafana is added to the website front end?

Are there any plugins or third-party tools available or not?